# Implement a TypeConverter for descriptions to Enum in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using `DescriptionAttribute` on Enums to provide a description that includes spaces.  I've created some extension methods that will return the string description of an enum and/or return the enum value from a string description.

Now I want my WebAPI to use these extension methods to handle Enum Type Conversion instead of the default TypeConverter so that I can pass a value like `"Car Wash"` and have it mapped to an Enum.

Is there a way to override the default string to Enum TypeConverter?

**Environment**
.NetCore 2.x

**Update - my current code**

My current code does great when the Controller serializes an object to JSON to be sent to the client.  Given the below `Enum`, an enum value of 0 will result in the client getting a string "Mental Health" -- perfect.  However, now when the client sends "Mental Health" back to the server -- I need that converted back into `AgencyTpes.MentalHealth`.  Right now, the binding engine throws an error.

```
//Example Enum
public enum AgencyTypes {
   [Description("Mental Health")]
   MentalHealth,
   Corrections,
   [Description("Drug & Alcohol")]
   DrugAndAlcohol,
   Probation
}
```

My Enum Extensions That Work With `DescriptionAttribute`

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToDisplayString(this Enum values)
    {
        var attribute = value.GetType().GetMember(value.ToString())
           .FirstOrDefault()?.GetCustomAttribute<DescriptionAttribute>();
        return attribute ?.Description ?? value.ToString();
     }

     public static object GetValueFromDescription(string description, Type enumType)
     {
         return Convert.ChangeType(LookupDescription(description,enumType),enumType);
     }

     public static T GetValueFromDescription<T>(string description) where T: struct
     {
        return (T)LookupDescription(description, typeof(T));
     }

     private static object LookupDescription(string description, Type enumType)
     {
        if(!enumType.IsEnum)
           throw new ArgumentException("Type provided must be an Enum", enumType.Name);

        foreach(var field in enumType.GetFields())
        {
           var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, tyepof(DescriptionAttribute)) as DescriptionAttribute;
           if((attribute != null && attribute.Description == description)
               || field.Name == description)
           {
              return field.GetValue(null);
           }
         }
         throw new ArgumentException($"Requested value for '{description}' in enum {enumType.Name} was not found", nameof(description));
     }
}
```

My JSON override to enable Controllers to convert enum to string

```
//Startup.cs
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(Compatibility.Version_2_2)
  .AddJsonOptions(options => 
  {
     options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringAnnotationEnumConverter());
  });


public class StringAnnotationEnumConverter : StringEnumConverter
{
   public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
      var token = JToken.Load(reader);
      var value = token.ToString();
      if(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
          return EnumExtensions.GetValueFromDescription(value, objectType);
      else
          return base.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);
   }

   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
   {
       if(value == null)
       {
          writer.WriteNull();
          return;
       }

       Enum e = (Enum)value;
       string enumName = e.ToDisplayString();
       if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enumName))
          throw new JsonSerializationException(String.Format("Integer value {0} is not allowed.",e.ToString("D")));

       writer.WriteValue(enumName);
    }
}
```

**Update 2 - WebAPI**

Here is the example code of the Controller & Domain Object

```
public class Agency 
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
   public AgencyTypes AgencyType {get; set;}
   ...
 }


 [ApiController]
 public class AgencyController : ControllerBase
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Agency([FromForm] Agency agency)
    {
       ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/regisdiogo/27f62ef83a804668eb0d9d0f63989e3e) link sir. Would this be a pointer in the right direction? You would of course have to implement your own converter.

Comment: I don't think that helps.  I already have the converter added as shown in that example.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that the WebAPI TypeConverter takes advantage of the Converters added to the JsonOptions.

Comment: Does that help?  That's all the code I currently have -- now I just need to know how to get the WebAPI binding engine to use my converter to convert the string into the enum.

Comment: @RHarris Apply the converter directly on the model member so the binder will use it to deserialize the value

Comment: I tried adding `[TypeConverter(typeof(StringAnnotationEnumConverter))]` but I get a System.FormatException in System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.  I'm wondering if its because `StringEnumConverter` is not of type `TypeConverter`

Comment: I'm curious if there is any way to just "override" the way the default model binder handles enums.  I would be fine with all enums across my system being handled by my `StringAnnotationEnumConverter`

Comment: @RHarris did you place a break point on the ReadJson method in your converter?  Just curious to know if it gets hit and if so what the actual problem is

Comment: @Darkonekt I did and it does not get hit - I get the error that I mentioned above first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try overriding the default `EnumConverter` to do your custom attribute check

```
public class MyEnumConverter: EnumConveter {
    public MyEnumConverter(Type type) : base(type) {
    }


    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value) {
        if (value is string) {
            var enumString = (string)value;
            return EnumExtensions.GetValueFromDescription(enumString, EnumType);
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

And decorating your enum with `TypeConverter` attribute

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(MyEnumConverter))]
public enum AgencyTypes {
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Mental Health")]
    MentalHealth,
    Corrections,
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Drug & Alcohol")]
    DrugAndAlcohol,
    Probation
}
```